# Jitterbit Client start error:

Tags: java, java-5, jitterbit

I have installed jittrbit client 4.0.7.14. I am trying to start using

```
jitterbit_client
```

I got following error:

```
The specified Java(TM) Virtual machine '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0' is not in the current users        PATH
The Jitterbit client requires Java 1.5.0.
You can download it for free from Sun: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/download.jsp
Also check out http://www.jitterbit.com/forums.
```

and my java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)
```

my $JAVA_HOME variable contails:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0
```

and $PATH variable is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0/bin
```

Where am I going wrong?