# Jitterbit studio start error:

Tags: java-6, jitterbit

Hi I have installed jitterbit5.0 on ubuntu 12.04  I am starting it using both from application menu and using

```
   jitterbit-studio50
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class       java.awt.EventQueue
at org.jitterbit.integration.client.main.IntegrationMain.showStartupError(IntegrationMain.java:85)
at org.jitterbit.integration.client.main.IntegrationMain.main(IntegrationMain.java:49)
```

where I goes wrong? and my Java version is:

```
 java version "1.6.0_37"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
 Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Problem Has been solved its because of java version my os is 64 bit and I was using 32 bit jdk 1.6.0 I removed that and now I am using jdk1.7.0 .it fixed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jitterbit Client start error:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688474/jitterbit-client-start-error)

Comment: @GaneshPatil are you using Jitterbit. I have some question, will you be available ?

Comment: @Sahal: Currently I am not using Jitterbit but you can post your question here so we will look into it.

Comment: Can you please tell me for what purpose you have used Jitterbit ? What was your requirement ?

Comment: Actually in my one application we were using jitterbit as a integration tool between my application and [salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1). using that  we were map my db fields to salesforce lead fields and we were upload data on salesforce and similarly we were retrieving data from salesforce. but currently we have replaced that jitterbit tool with cakePHP console script.